# org.hibernate.HibernateException: instance not of expected entity type

Tags: hibernate

Any idea on how to map multilevel inheritance using hibernate mapping file. I have the below scenario.

```
A
|
|
B
|
|
C
```

- B is extended from A
- C is extended from B

I have a class P which contains A. P has a many to one relation to A.

Below is the extract from the hibernate mapping file for P

```
<many-to-one name="info"  class="com.test.A" column="info" not-null="true" lazy="false" cascade="all" unique="true"/>
```

Now when I am trying to store P

- When P contains B it works.
- When P contains C I get the below error

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: instance not of expected entity type: com.test.C is not a: com.test.A.

My question is that C is also extended from A so when B etended from A can be stored then why C extended from B cannot be stored.

Thanks
Gaurav